# Increment character in a string

Tags: vb.net

I have a 2 character string composed only of the 26 capital alphabet letters, `'A'` through `'Z'`.

We have a way of knowing the "highest" used value (e..g `"IJ"` in `{"AB", "AC", "DD", "IH", "IJ"}`). We'd like to get the "next" value (`"IK"` if `"IJ"` is the "highest").

```
Function GetNextValue(input As String) As String
  Dim first = input(0)
  Dim last = input(1)
  If last = "Z"c Then
    If first = "Z"c Then Return Nothing

    last = "A"c
    first++
  Else
    last++
  EndIf

  Return first & last
End Function
```

Obviously `char++` is not valid syntax in VB.NET. C# [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838589/945456) allows you to do this. Is there something <strike>shorter</strike> less ugly than this that'd increment a letter? (Note: `Option Strict` is on)

```
CChar(CInt(char)+1).ToString
```

**Edit**: As noted in comment/answers, the above line won't even compile. You can't convert from Char -> Integer at all in VB.NET.

Comment: My suggestion is make a BASE 26 converter and convert the string to a decimal(BASE 10), add one, and convert the decimal back to BASE 26. Alternatively, you can always convert to ASCII Codes and add one, but this logic gets hackish because you'd need to write special code in to  handle the edges (where Z should turn into A and the first character would increment)

Comment: As a note, the C# version works because C# will implicitly convert from char to int16. This behaviour then makes the `+`, and by extension the `+=` operator work. EricLippert has an interesting answer/blog post on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503430/implicit-type-cast-in-c-sharp/1504959#1504959

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tidiest so far is simply:

```
Dim a As Char = "a"
a = Chr(Asc(a) + 1)
```

This still needs handling for the `"z"` boundary condition though, depending on what behaviour you require.

Interestingly, converting `char++` through developerfusion suggests that `char += 1` should work. It doesn't. (VB.Net doesn't appear to implicitly convert from char to int16 as C# does).

To make things really nice you can do the increment in an Extension by passing the char byref. This now includes some validation and also a reset back to `a`:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub Inc(ByRef c As Char)

    'Remember if input is uppercase for later
    Dim isUpper = Char.IsUpper(c)

    'Work in lower case for ease
    c = Char.ToLower(c)

    'Check input range
    If c < "a" Or c > "z" Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException

    'Do the increment
    c = Chr(Asc(c) + 1)

    'Check not left alphabet
    If c > "z" Then c = "a"

    'Check if input was upper case
    If isUpper Then c = Char.ToUpper(c)

End Sub
```

Then you just need to call:

```
Dim a As Char = "a"        
a.Inc() 'a is now = "b"
```

Comment: Yes, was just trying for a nice way around it, but nothing really.

Comment: Although all the other solutions are good, this is what I ended up going with, so I've accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way -- even `CChar(CInt(char)+1).ToString` doesn't work.  It's even uglier:

```
CChar(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Char.ConvertToUtf32(myCharacter, 0) + 1))
```

but of course you could always put that in a function with a short name or, like Jon E. pointed out, an extension method.

Comment: Using `AscW` and `ChrW` from `Microsoft.VisualBasic` also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will support up to 10 characters, but can easily support more.

```
Private Sub Test
    MsgBox(ConvertBase10ToBase26(ConvertBase26ToBase10("AA") + 1))
End Sub

Public Function ConvertBase10ToBase26(ToConvert As Integer) As String
    Dim pos As Integer = 0

    ConvertBase10ToBase26 = ""
    For pos = 10 To 0 Step -1
        If ToConvert >= (26 ^ pos) Then
            ConvertBase10ToBase26 += Chr((ToConvert \ (26 ^ pos)) + 64)
            ToConvert -= (26 ^ pos)
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Function ConvertBase26ToBase10(ToConvert As String) As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer = 0

    ConvertBase26ToBase10 = 0
    For pos = 0 To ToConvert.Length - 1
        ConvertBase26ToBase10 += (Asc(ToConvert.Substring(pos, 1)) - 64) * (26 ^ pos)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This is brilliant Ghost!. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Function IncBy1(input As String) As String
    Static ltrs As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim first As Integer = ltrs.IndexOf(input(0))
    Dim last As Integer = ltrs.IndexOf(input(1))
    last += 1
    If last = ltrs.Length Then
        last = 0
        first += 1
    End If
    If first = ltrs.Length Then Return Nothing
    Return ltrs(first) & ltrs(last)
End Function
```

This DOES assume that the code is only two chars, and are A-Z only.

Answer (score -1):

Dim N as String = ""

Dim chArray As Char = Convert.ToChar(N)

```
    Dim a As String = CChar(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Char.ConvertToUtf32(chArray, 0) + 1))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would also recommend you to use the formatting guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code correctly.

Comment: Format your code section please and add short description for your code snippet.